# Only first start date and last finish date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, reporting

I have two db tables in the first one `seminarsessions`, there is:

```
     id     | knowntime    |  
    --------+--------------+ 
       1    | 1            |  
       2    | 0            |  
       3    | 1            |
```

In the second table `seminarsessions_date` there are the `timestamps` with for each `date` and the `datefrom` and `dateuntil` for this date:

```
   id | dateid | seminarsessionid | datefrom | dateuntil
    --------+--------------+------+----------+----------
    1 | 312     | 3               |1462863600| 1462867200
    2 | 123     | 3               |1450944000| 1451206800
    3 | 543     | 3               |1464868800| 1464872400
```

How to display for `each` seminarsession with **knowntime** only the `first` **datefrom** and the `last` **dateuntil**?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a *derived table* that contains the already aggregated values from table `seminarsessions_date`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.knowntime, t2.datefrom, t2.dateuntil
FROM seminarsessions
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT seminarsessionid, 
          MIN(datefrom) AS datefrom,
          MAX(dateuntil) AS dateuntil
   FROM seminarsessions_date
   GROUP BY seminarsessionid 
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.seminarsessionid
```

Derived table `t2` contains the *first* `datefrom` and the *last* `dateuntil` value per `seminarsessionid`.